# Java 8 stream flatMap allow null check for each list in the nested list?

Tags: java

I have a nested list to loop through in `pre Java 8`. My example is very similar to [loop through nested list in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630352/nested-lists-with-streams-in-java8) which is a great example to follow then I realized that I need to check for `null` for each `list`. Plz refer to the below example. If the last condition is met then return true by short-circuiting.

However I am not sure how to check `null` for each `list` using `list.stream().flatMap()`.

```
for(A a : ListA) {
        if(a.getListB() != null && !a.getListB().isEmpty()) {
            for(B b : a.getListB()) {
                if(b.getListC() != null && !p.getListC().isEmpty()) {
                    for(C c : b.getListC()) {
                        return (c.name.equalsIgnoreCase("john"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of gross but it works. You essentially check if listB is not null and create a Stream of B. Then filter through Stream of B and check if ListC is null and if not map to a Stream of C. Then just simply check if any of C match the argument.

```java
boolean found = listA.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getListB() != null)
    .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
    .filter(b -> b.getListC() != null)
    .flatMap(b -> b.getListC().stream())
    .anyMatch(c -> c.name.equalsIgnoreCase("john"));
```